# Bootstrap Navbar doesnt scroll on smaller screensize

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, sass

I am trying to make a custom navbar with bootstrap. This navbar has a mega menu inside, aka a dropdown inside a dropdown. On wider screens it works perfect, but on smaller screens, it doesn't let the user scroll down to see the rest of the elements.

Do you have any solution to this?

Here is the code that i came up with:

HTML

```html
        <div class="baraDeNavigare">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light  fixed-top  ">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">☰</button>
            <a class="navbar-brand col-2" >
                <img src="../images/Layer_2.png"  >
                <img src="../images//2-layers.png"  >
            </a>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">





          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-row-reverse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav  ">

                <li class="nav-item dropdown menu-large">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Services
                     </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu">
                        <div class="row">
                            <li class="col-md-2 dropdown-item">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header text-white ">Product Categories</li>

                                    <li><a href="#">Accesories</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Alcohol</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Art</a></li> 
                                    <li><a href="#">Books</a></li> 
                                    <li><a href="#">Drinks</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Electronics</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Flowers & Plants</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Food</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-2 dropdown-item">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">.</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Gadgets</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Garden</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Grocery</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Jewelry</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Kids & Baby</a></li> 
                                    <li><a href="#">Men's Fashion</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mobile</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-2 dropdown-item">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header">.</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Motorcycles</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Music</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Office</a></li>
                                    <li> <a href="#">Pets</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Romantic</a></li>
                                    <li> <a href="#">Sport</a></li>
                                    <li> <a href="#">Toys</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="col-md-2 dropdown-item">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="dropdown-header text-white">Sale</li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Alcohol</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Art</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Books</a> </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Drinks</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Electronics</a> </li> 
                                    <li><a href="#">Flowers & Plants</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Food</a> </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>

                            <li class="col-md-3 offset-1 dropdown-item">
                                <ul>
                                    <img src="../images/Layer_9.png"  class="img-fluid" alt="Woman shopping">
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </div>
                    </ul>


              </li>


                      <li class="nav-item ">
                           <a class="nav-link" href="#">company</a>
                      </li>

                     <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">library</a>
                     </li>
        </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

and this is the SCSS i have

```css
    .dropdown-header{
    margin-bottom:10px;
    }

    .menu-large {
    position: static !important;
    overflow:auto;
    }

    .megamenu {
    padding: 45px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: $albastruNav;

    }

    .megamenu > div > li > ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    }

    .megamenu > div > li > ul > li {
    list-style: none;
    }

    .megamenu > div > li > ul > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: white;
    white-space: normal;
    }

    .dropdown-header{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:16px;
    color:$albastruNav;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    }

    .dropdown-item:hover{
    color:inherit;
    background-color: inherit;

    }

    @media (max-width: 768px) {
    .megamenu {
      margin-left: 0;
      margin-right: 0;
    }
    .megamenu > li {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    .megamenu > li:last-child {
      margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .megamenu.dropdown-header {
      padding: 3px 15px !important;
    }
    .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
      color: #fff;
    }
    }
```

Comment: i had this too, you have to use `overflow:scroll` probably on `.megamenu`

Comment: it doesn't work, unfortunately :(